# Split string using a delimiter then saving to different variables

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, string, espressif

I have a string that looks something like this "43;27;42;27". It is the data from 4 DHT22 temperature sensors, i need to splice this string every ";" and save the number to a variable. In the end, I will have 4 variables, each one for every number. Thanks!
The data comes from another esp wirelessly and I need the data in different strings to a nextion display.
I could also change the delimiters to differ from each other, I am posting this question because I am not sure how i should go about writing all of these 4 values in a string then also "decoding" these strings and assigning each one to a variable.

Comment: Have you googled for something like "Arduino parse string"?

Comment: Was not sure how I would go about googling this, looking into it right now and I post the answer. Thanks!

Comment: `splice` means `connect` ... the words you want to search are `split` and `parse`